# Open remote Meteor DDP Connection behind reverse proxy

Tags: nginx, meteor

I am struggling to open a connection from `https://siteA.com` to `https://siteB.com` using Meteor's `DDP.connect()` where both servers reside behind nginx reverse proxies forwarding from http to https.

Things work fine in development. In production, when I run `DDP.connect('siteB.com')` in the console of siteA, I receive:

```
Mixed Content: The page at 'https://siteA.com/' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure XMLHttpRequest endpoint 'http://siteB.com/sockjs/info?cb=zw6j36l90y'.  This request has been blocked; the content must be served over HTTPS.
```

In my current nginx configuration for siteB, I have the following (in relevant part, lmk if more is required):

```
server {
  listen 80 default_server;
  location / {
    rewrite ^ https://$server_name$request_uri? permanent;
  }
}

server {
  listen 443 ssl spdy;
  add_header Access-Control-Allow-Origin 'https://siteA.com';
  proxy_pass http://localhost:3000;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-For $proxy_add_x_forwarded_for;
  proxy_set_header Host $http_host;
  proxy_set_header X-Real-IP $remote_addr;
  proxy_set_header X-Forwarded-Proto https;
  proxy_set_header X-Nginx-Proxy true;
  proxy_redirect off;
}
```

I get that it's complaining that the request terminates in an http endpoint (http://localhost:3000) but I'm not sure what to do about it.

If I change siteB's nginx config to `proxy_pass https://localhost:3000` it results in a `502 Bad Gateway`.

I have tried things both with and without Meteor's `force-ssl` package on siteB.

Neither site includes Meteor's `browser-policy` package - based on my reading the default setting without the package should allow me to connect anywhere as is.

I also tried `DDP.connect("ws://siteB.com");` but this resulted in:

```
XMLHttpRequest cannot load ws://siteB.com/sockjs/info?cb=9lahswe7_9. Cross origin requests are only supported for protocol schemes: http, data, chrome, chrome-extension, https, chrome-extension-resource.
```

Should I be listening on a different port? Is there an nginx config setting to whitelist this request? Any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

After some initial googling here a small hint:  [Mixed Content: The page at 'XYZ' was loaded over HTTPS, but requested an insecure over https](http://www.paulsodimu.co.uk/Post/Quick-Tip-Using-Google-Fonts-Over-HTTPS)

...even though it talks about stylesheets not XMLHttpRequest it is definately related